Angular 16 Unknown argument: standalone
I'm starting a new project with Angular 16 for testing purposes. I decided to create a project with the standalone option, however, I get the following error when I execute the command "ng new todo-list-16 --standalone":

These are my current settings, is anything missing?


Yeah, I'm looking at the documentation to verify if that's possible. I was following a tutorial that my boss recommended, and in it, the guy generates the project already in 'standalone' format.

As you can see in your ng version, you have installed angular cli with version 14. If you want to generate angular with version 16, you first need to update your angular cli:
npm install -g @angular/cli@16.2.8


Great! I uninstalled version 14 and then installed version 16. It didn't give an error, but it didn't perform any of the operations. Only now did I realize that none of them had been carried out. I restarted the computer and redid the operations, and everything worked fine. Thank you, you made me see the mistake.
